# Multiple nested hash in the parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some nested hashes. For example, I set a parameter.

```
params = {
  id: @account.id,
  account: {
    'raw_one_call_settings' => {
      'service_areas' => {
        '0' => {'id' => 'QWE', 'ivrid' => ''},
        '1' => {'id' => 'RTY', 'ivrid' => ''}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that for it hash no permit.

`params.require(:account).permit(raw_one_call_settings: {service_areas:{}})`

I get:

`=> <ActionController::Parameters {"raw_one_call_settings"=><ActionController::Parameters {"service_areas"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>, "1"=><ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true>`

How do I get the values?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
params.require(:account).permit(raw_one_call_settings: { service_areas: [:id, :ivrid] })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
params.require(:account)
          .permit(:id, :account => [:raw_one_call_settings =>{:service_areas=> [:id, :ivrid] }])
```

Comment: @Vadim B if you satisfied with my answer then make it correct and vote up